# Can't Connect to Azure Storage Account

Tags: .net, networking, azure, storage

I have A storage Account on Azure that i can successfully connect to from a computer.
 And i can't connect to it from another computer using the same account name and key. What could have been causing this problem?

Comment: what is the error message it gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason for this could be that the second computer you have is behind a firewall where the port required for storage communication is blocked. Is your second computer in an organization VPN/LAN if yes, then your organization firewall might be blocking the communication

Comment: Actually it turned out that my computer's clock was behind in few hours.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me for the same reason as OP but my clock was just a few minutes offset.
To fix this on Windows 8 go to "Change date and time settings", click on the "Internet Time" tab, click "Change Settings" and then "Update now" and the system will synchronize with a Windows server and all will be okay :)